# How to Batch ACL Request in Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

The **Document List API** allows you to [batch ACL requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#batching_acl_requests) to save bandwidth.

Is there a similar capability using the **Drive API**?

Answer (score 0):

There is a generalized batching solution in the new APIs and supported with Drive. See [Is there a way to make batched calls using the Drive SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999355/is-there-a-way-to-make-batched-calls-using-the-drive-sdk) for an example of how to batch requests with Python. Most, if not all of the current API clients have batch support.