# Is there a way to make batched calls using the Drive SDK?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Some of the older Google APIs ( like contacts ) allow you to make batched calls.
Is this possible with the Python Drive API ?

Specifically, I would like to know if it is possible to get comments for multiple files in one API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example after mining the documentation, assuming you have credentials stored in a variable creds:

```
def list_animals(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        # Do something with the exception.
        pass
    else:
        # Do something with the response.
        pass

def list_farmers(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        # Do something with the exception.
        pass
    else:
        # Do something with the response.
        pass

service_ = authHandler.CreateService('drive', 'v2', creds)

batch = BatchHttpRequest()

batch.add(service_.changes().list(), list_animals)
batch.add(service_.changes().list(), list_farmers)
batch.execute(http=authHandler.getHttp(creds))
```

Comment: Additional documentation on this here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch